# Resin JSP compiler error

Tags: java, jsp, resin

I'm getting such error while compiling JSPs during resin server start up.

> [null] Exception in thread "main"
>   com.caucho.java.JavaCompileException:  : error:
>   getJspBody() has protected access in SimpleTagSupport [null]
>   *jsp*_script__tag_3.doTag(pageContext, _jsp_context13, out, *jsp*_script__tag_3.getJspBody(), _jsp_LayoutComponentTag_2); .... [null]     at
>   com.caucho.java.InternalCompiler.executeInt(InternalCompiler.java:254)
>   [null]    at
>   com.caucho.java.InternalCompiler.compileInt(InternalCompiler.java:102)
>   [null]    at
>   com.caucho.java.AbstractJavaCompiler.run(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:111)
>   [null]    at
>   com.caucho.env.thread.ResinThread.runTasks(ResinThread.java:164)
>   [null]    at com.caucho.env.thread.ResinThread.run(ResinThread.java:130)

Environment:

- Resin version 4.0.23
- Java version 1.7.0_40
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

Comment: Can you post your jsp file?

Comment: It would also be good to see the source code for the custom tag class.